Are coding theory questions allowed?
Is it allowed to ask theoretical questions about coding theory?

Yes. Coding theory and cryptography share quite a bit of background and techniques, and Crypto.SE seems more appropriate than Math.SE or CSTheory.SE.

I think we should determine whether or not questions are appropriate based on our criteria for this site, not on whether or not they could be handled somewhere else (especially given that other SE sites may change their perspectives over time). We don't want to be a dumping ground for anything that might be related to cryptography in some way.

No.  I would recommend that this site maintain its focus on cryptography.  I would recommend that such questions be judged by a simple question: if it is relevant to crypto, it is on-topic; otherwise, it is not.
Therefore, questions about coding-theory based crypto should be on-topic, but questions about coding theory that aren't connected to cryptography should be treated as off-topic.
